# how to resize video image, image path fetched from json

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2

I am getting data from youtube based on video id using json.

This code is working properly. I am fetching image path based on image id.
now I would like  to resize the image(original image size is approx 408X306) i want to resize it 200px X200px

I am getting only url of video image

How to do this.

I am using jquery,java,struts2.

My code is

```
var video_id=KsnHky4wv5w;

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){

         alert(' \nImage path:'+data.data.thumbnail.hqDefault);


        });
```

Comment: So you want to distort the video? This won't keep the original aspect...

Comment: I thought the question was mistagged as java, but java is appropriate now